# Installing ubuntu in a backup harddisk in unallocated space

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I have one 120 GB SSD, formatted in NTFS and storing 80GB of my data backup. There's 40 GB of unused space on that drive, and I don't intend to dual boot Windows and Linux. I want to install current Ubuntu in it; is it possible? Also, what is the suitable space required for the different folders and partitions?

In Ubuntu, I wanted to install python (numpy and matplotlib), C++ and Fortran. So need guidance. This is my first experience with Ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: I an not using dual-boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desktop Ubuntu requires [25GB for its installation including all its files as folders](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements#Ubuntu_Desktop_Edition). 30GB will give you plenty of room to add those tools as well as install one of the 10 official [Ubuntu desktop versions](http://releases.ubuntu.com). The Ubuntu desktop installer, Ubiquity, in a [LiveUSB](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) will allow you during the install process to [shrink your Windows NTFS partition and make room to install Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Preparing_to_Install_Ubuntu_alongside_Windows). Your mileage may vary, of course, once you start adding things beyond what you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you but I am not using windows at this time. I have unformatted space of 40GB in my SSD that I wanted to use. May I know how much space I allocate to home boot and other ....

Comment: Thank you. It can be closed as solved.